# Como acessar um dado de dentro do objeto, estando no mesmo objeto

Tags: javascript

```
let carryData = {
    prova: Number(34),
    semanal:Number(345),
    aExtra:Number(543),
    total:??? //quero o valor da prova, nesse mesmo objeto 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você quer declarar a propriedade `total` com o mesmo valor, terá que duplicar o valor atribuído a `prova`.

Agora se `total` é apenas uma propriedade para acessar o valor, você pode declarar ela como um *getter*.

```js
let carryData = {
    prova: 34,
    semanal: 345,
    aExtra: 543,
    get total() {
        return this.prova;
    }
};

console.log(carryData.total);
```